# Running code in android studio using sqlite

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, localhost

Hi I'm a beginner and I'm running this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8-SnOF0wkI , but I'm stuck at here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yv6RqNoHadg&t=8s . Because the registration form did not connect to the database. It says, server error. I'm using my ip address to connect. But I can't find any reason why I cant connect to the database.

Please help me

Comment: post part of your code here

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B3CAPnUtJXqnOV9YbDBNb3hCeUk?usp=sharing here is my code

Comment: Not really familiar with  google drive. Can I clone your project from google drive ?

Comment: yeah sure you may

Comment: do you know how ?

Comment: download all three file and insert the 'potslogin' into htdocs, the 'POTS5' is my android project. and 'userdb' is my database. you can right click the file and click download

Comment: perhaps you miss to define your port ? `String register_url = "http://192.168.43.76:3306/potslogin/register.php";`

Comment: paste your logcat error here

Comment: please copy/paste the relevant parts of your code instead of a link to some external resource. that will make it easier to answer, and to reference for future readers.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I've found it I changed it to "http://192.168.43.76:10080/potslogin/register.php" and it worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using your public IP address not the one provided by router. If your problem persists then you may set up port forwarding so that you can easily connect to your database.

I would recommend you to follow up with udacity tutorials they are much better. Also as an alternative you may use firebase to configure and set up on a server it will make much of processing easier